# Same python code runs 20 times slower in Jupyter Notebook compared to command line

Tags: python, jupyter, streamlit

I have a python code which uses Hugging Face Transformers to run an NLP task on a PDF document. When I run this code in Jupyter Notebook, it takes more than 1.5 hours to complete. I then setup the same code to run via a locally hosted Streamlit web app. To my surprise, it ran in under 5 mins!

I believe I am comparing apples to apples because:

- I am analyzing the same PDF document in each case
- Since the Streamlit app is locally hosted, all computation is running on my laptop CPU. I am not using any Hugging Face virtual resources. The HF models are being downloaded to my computer.
- The Jupyter Notebook is also running locally on my computer
- The `.py` file is generated from the Jupyter Notebook using 'streamlit-juypter' which just takes the Python code in the notebook and adds a few Streamlit statements

So, essentially same code running on same data using same hardware.

The only differences I can think of which may explain this are:

- Streamlit is running a `.py` python file from the command line instead of a `.ipynb` notebook
- Streamlit is running inside a virtual environment instead of my main Python installation

Has anyone ever experienced something like this? Can running the same python code from the command line result in 20x greater speed?

**Edit**: As suggested by @Wayne, I compared the output of `pip list` between my main Python installation and the venv and found some differences. So I updated all the core packages being used by the NLP task to latest versions and now run-time is the same. Though I still don't know which package was responsible and it probably doesn't matter now.

MS Excel comparison of package versions
[image: comparison of package versions]

Comment: You are actually giving very little details for anyone to go on here. The HuggingFace environment vs. your local are identical? What are the differences among all the involved packages? Second you are running one in a Jupyter notebook and one in an streamlit app using a `.py` file. In the notebook, what are you using though? Running that same `.py` file with `%run` in the notebook. Using any IPython magics or is what is run in the `.ipynb` file pure Python? How much resources are you using on your computer vs HuggingFace? Do you have a powerul computer vs free virtual on HuggingFace?

Comment: Added more detail. Would it help if I posted the `.ipynb` code and `.py` code side-by-side for comparison?

Comment: I'm still not understanding where the Jupyter Notebook is running? That's running locally on your own machine, too? And how the environment differs from Streamlit is using. You should be able to run `conda list` or `pip list` in each one and see the differences.

Comment: The Jupyter Notebook is running locally on my computer too. But Streamlit is using a virtual env which has only the packages needed for the task it's doing. Jupyter is using my main Python installation which would have many other packages installed over time.

Comment: Yes, and as I mentioned normally you run the commands I put and compare the versions of the pertinent involved packages. It may well be that one of the critical packages involved is much older and not as optimized as the one the other place. Or one version is known to have a salient flaw. Please refer to my first sentence of my first comment. Please read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Note that it says, "Remember that you can edit your question at any time!".

Comment: Not sure if you have noticed but each time I reply to a comment I also update my question with additional info. In any case, my question is "Has anyone ever experienced something like this?". I am less interested in diagnosing the reason for the diff in runtime than knowing whether others have also experienced this. I already know that package versions etc. are the same between Jupyter and cmd.

Comment: "I already know that package versions etc. are the same between Jupyter and cmd." Those details were not provided and since there is a virtual environment involved that is separate from your main system Python installation, that is unlikely. I think that StackOverflow is more suitable for diagnosing the reason than open-ended questions about have others experienced things. Keeping questions practical is emphasized if you following the guide I linked.